# How do I write a django query to join on a field and a condition

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm struggling to write a django query which widens data like the below sql statement.

```
select 
       t1.id
      ,t2a.value value_a
      ,t2b.value value_b

  from t1

 inner join t2 as t2a
    on t1.id = t2a.request_id and t2a.type = 'a'
 inner join t2 as t2b
    on t1.id = t2b.request_id and t2b.type = 'b'
```

Any help converting the above sql to a django query would be really appreciated!

Comment: You can use this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries) where you can write your SQL query in Django directly

Comment: Thanks, Bharat, I know about this option, I was just hoping there was a django queryset way to write it.

Comment: Try with select_related() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: I tried with select_related(). I could only manage to get a join on a single field. Am trying again to see if I can join on a field and a condition.

Comment: Could you provide a real world example where this is needed? This simply seems like a bad database architecture.

Comment: @emihir0 a very simplified version is I have a table which stores requests (t1), each request has 2 or more parts. These parts are called type 'a', type 'b', etc. They are stored in a different table (t2), one row per part, and hold information that I need (value). t2 has a foreign key to t1. If I simply join t1 onto t2 I will get 2+ rows per request, one for each part. I need a single row (django object) per request, holding the value that I need for both type 'a' and 'b'. Therefore I need to join t1 onto t2 twice with the extra condition, this gives a single object holding all the data.